# only submit a certain amount of data

Tags: jquery

I have a program with 5 input boxes and each box is shown on its own as I hide the previous box and boxes after the current from which is being shown. I am trying to get my program to only submit data from the current box and the previously shown boxes. In case the user submits data from a box in the middle but they have completed all the boxes, but they only want results from the middle from backwards. (If this makes sense)

The way I am trying to do this is to add all of the boxes input into an object then selecting which bits of data to send from that object using AJAX.

The code I have so far is:

```
var mainContainer = {};

/* Input Timer */

var typingTimer;               //timer identifier
var doneTypingInterval = 500;

$('#width').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#width').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(refresh, doneTypingInterval);
        width = $(this).val();
        mainContainer = {
            width : width
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(mainContainer));
    }
});

// When Fix Changes start countdown
$('#fixType').change(function() {
    clearTimeout(typingTimer);
    if ($('#fixType').val) {
        typingTimer = setTimeout(refresh, doneTypingInterval);
        fix = $("#fixType option:selected").text();
        mainContainer = {
            fix : fix
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(mainContainer));
    }
});
```

I have only done it with 2 boxes so far just to test if this works or not. However, when I add width to the main container It doesn't add it to the main container object which fix uses. How can I get it so it adds all of my inputs so all of the `.keyups` can see it?

UPDATE:

If I enter a width, the width is added to the object and is alerted as you can see here: http://puu.sh/nY2Mf/194e8f0d1a.png

But when I go on to fix and enter a fixture type it doesn't display the width which I added to the object previously: http://puu.sh/nY2RR/fbc840a660.png

Comment: Can you please clarify with an image or example? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem that i see is how you try to "add" to your object `mainContainer`

When you write this:

```
mainContainer = {
    width : width
}
```

You are defining `mainContainer` to look like this `{width : width }`. You can't then write

```
mainContainer = {
        fix : fix
    }
```

because that rewrites `mainContainer`. to **only** be `{ fix : fix }`

Instead, write

```
mainContainer.width = width;
mainContainer.fix = fix;
```

`console.log(mainContainer)` should then return an object with both `fix` and `width` properties

```
mainContainer {
    width: width,
    fix: fix
}
```

Answer (score 0):

disabled inputs don't get posted so you can disable any inputs outside of your current container.

```
$('input:not(#container input)').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

as you have not posted any html. I just used example selectors.